# Add commits to outdated Pull request

Tags: git, github, branch, open-source, pull-request

so i am contributing to an open source project. So far I have:

- Made my own fork
- Committed some changes and opened a PR from 'main' on my fork
- I have received feedback on these changes, and would like to commit some edits in reference to this feedback onto the PR

The problem is, I have since made additional changes to my 'main' branch of my fork. I am wondering if there is a way to go back the commit at which the PR was made, make the edits and then commit them to the PR, so it can be merged. How would I go about this?

What I have tried doing is checking out the commit at which the PR was made, making the edits and then committing to 'main' on my fork, creating a new branch. But from there I don't know how to link these to the PR I initially opened.

I imagine this problem can be prevented in the future as surely it is quite common - if so then how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, the best practice is to *not* work on branches that are common with your upstream repository (like `main`, which exists in the upstream repository you have forked).

Make sure, by the way, to add to your local clone a remote named "upstream", referencing the original repository you have forked. It differs from "origin", which represents your remote forked repository that you own.

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/other/repository
```

You always work on local branches which are unique to your fork.

Second, you always rebase your PR branch on top of the target branch (`upstream/main` in your case)

Your current situation is:

```
          p--p--p (feature for PR)
         /
--u--u--u         (upstream/main, origin/main)
         \
          m--m--m (main, extra work)
```

You can ignore your `main` branch: you want to do a PR on top of upstream/main. Make sure the target branch is up-to-date: `git fetch upstream`.

Then rebase only your feature commit:

```
git rebase --onto upstream/main $(git merge-base feature upstream/main) feature
```

You would get:

```
             p'--p'--p' (feature rebased, for PR)
            /
--u--u--u--u            (upstream/main)
        |\
        |  m--m--m (main, extra work)
        |
   (origin/main)
```

You can then force push your feature branch to update your existing PR.

```
git switch feature
git push --force
```

Comment: Thanks - but am I doing these commands from my main branch or my feature branch. Also - when you write 'feature' in the commands, is this representative of the branch name or the commit id - thanks.

Comment: @archie "feature" is the name of your feature branch, the one you are working on, and have already been doing a PR in progress with. The rebase command will switch to that branch automatically, so you can do the rebase from any branch. Change "feature" by the name of the branch already involved in your PR.